# List<> .Tag Value in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a List<> collection which contains a bunch of images. Each object within the list has a .Tag value of type string.

These objects are just images of items like a Strawberry, Banana or a Table Chair etc...

I want to know how I can check if a certain string is equivalent to any of the .Tag strings within the List<> collection.

I know I can probably loop through but...Can't I use `listName.Contains(stringName)` somehow to qualify the .Tag?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this.

```
listname.Any(x=>x.TagName==stringName)
```